# I need a batch file to change one line of text in one directory to the same text file in a different directory

Tags: batch-file

Basically, I have a text file with one line of text `SetNumber=01` in 5 folders

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Test\test.txt
C:\Folder\Test\test.txt
C:\Test\test.txt 
etc.
```

I need to change this `SetNumber=01` to different numbers monthly, for instance `SetNumber=01` to `SetNumber=02`, in all these folders, and would like to run a batch file that would copy and replace this line of text from

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Test\test.txt
```

into

```
C:Folder\Test\test.txt. 
etc.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You want to change text in a text file. So you have to say specific, change which file to what. `for instance "SetNumber=01` is to cloudy.

Comment: The only thing I have tried is to run this: xcopy "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Text\""test.txt" "C:\Test\test.txt\" because I am having trouble with just copying the one certain line SetNumber=* What i need is to change the value for SetNumber and have it changed in each of the 5 folders.

Comment: OK, but change the value from what **to** what??

Answer (score 0):

OK, here we go. This copies the file `C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Test\test.txt` to all `..\test\test.txt` files on the current volume (they were **erased**). Remove the `echo` command, if the output is OK:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "sourcefile=C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\Test\test.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d \test.txt') do (
    set "fpath=%%~fi"
    if "!fpath:*test\test.txt=!"=="" if not "%sourcefile%"=="%%~fi" (
        echo copy "%sourcefile%" "%%~fi"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below change *all* files named **test.txt** in any folder in the disk by inserting this line "SetNumber=%1":

```
@echo off
for /R \ %%a in (test.txt) do echo SetNumber=%1> "%%a"
```

For example, if previous Batch file is called SetNumber.bat, you may change all the files to SetNumber=02 with this command:

```
setnumber=02
```

Antonio